# How to extend functionalities of Direct Connect clients ( Like linuxdcpp, dc++ )?

Tags: php, c++, python, p2p

Is there exist a way with which i can extend the functionalities of DC++ (better if linuxdcpp as i use linux).  I want to make **custom features** for myself using python or c++.

*For example:*

> On clicking the filename of a particular file.
>   the google search results of the file name is shown alongside, it would help.

---

So can i use php/python or similar language that would fetch the data from HTTP and show it inside dc client ?

**OR**

External php/python (or similar) script that would utilize the 'already running dc client' via API.

---

I googled a lot, and couldnt find any particular solution.

However i got landed onto this site
http://pydc.sourceforge.net/
which claims that it can be extended, but i am not an expert coder that i can build my own dc client onto previous one
.

Answer (score 0):

Try [eiskaltdc](https://github.com/negativ/eiskaltdcpp) . It has scripting support and command line interface but scripting can only be done in Qt(and some perl) and not in Python. There is another command line tool microdc2 which you will be able to extend (c/c++, no python here either).